# Convert assets to content uri

Tags: xamarin.android, assets

How do I convert assets into a content uri? `Asset.Open` returns a `System.IO.Stream`.

Is there anyway to convert that to a content uri? I need a content uri for the `InputConnectionCompat.CommitContent()` method.

Based on what I have seen on stack overflow, you could you use `file:///android_asset/[filename]`. But when I tried it, I got an error that said something like invalid content uri scheme.

Comment: That's wired, it should be work, please post more detail code about this?

Comment: @DianaLi - thanks for your help, the issue turned out to be cause from the api i was using instead of the line of code. I was using api 22. The InputConnectionCompat.CommitContent() was not available to api 25.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up serving the files out out the raw folder instead. But what I learned from this is that you can convert System.IO.Stream to a Java.IO.InputStream/Java.IO.OutputStream (or vice versa) by reading to bytes of one stream into the the other stream.